# @WebParam is always null in jetty serving soap

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jetty, jax-ws

I have a java app exposing an SOAP API through Jetty. I can successfully access my WSDL and forge a request, but the webparam sent is always null. I don't know how to debug this problem. 
Here i have a few snippets of the functions involved in the request.
I'll edit if you need more information:

```
@WebMethod(
        operationName = "findEvent"
    )
    public ServiceEventDto findEvent(
            @WebParam(name = "eventId") Long eventId) throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        Event event
                = EventServiceFactory.getService().findEvent(eventId);
        return EventToEventDtoConversor.toEventDto(event);
    }
```

This is the request:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eve="http://ws.udc.es/event">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <eve:findEvent>
        <eve:eventId>0</eve:eventId>
    </eve:findEvent>
</x:Body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so the code has findInvite and inviteId and the XML has findEvent and eventId

Comment: @SlipperySeal  Sorry, i did copy the wrong code, i'll fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your SOAP input is using the `eve` namespace prefix for the `eventId` input element.

Try this:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eve="http://ws.udc.es/event">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <eve:findEvent>
        <eventId>0</eventId>
    </eve:findEvent>
</x:Body>
```

I was able to recreate using the following service provider in Jetty 9.4:

Service endpoint interface:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace="http://ws.udc.es/event")
public interface SampleService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "findEvent")
        public ServiceEventDto findEvent(@WebParam(name = "eventId") Long eventId) throws InstanceNotFoundException;

}
```

Service implementation:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.example.sampleservice.SampleService", targetNamespace="http://ws.udc.es/event")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext ctx;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "findEvent")
    public ServiceEventDto findEvent(@WebParam(name = "eventId") Long eventId) throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("SampleServiceImpl: received eventId " + eventId);
        return new ServiceEventDto();
    }

}
```

When I use your original input with `<eve:eventId>0</eve:eventId>` I observe the following output:

`SampleServiceImpl: received eventId null`

When I use `<eventId>0</eventId>` I observe the expected output:

`SampleServiceImpl: received eventId 0`

**If, however, you are expected to accept `<eve:eventId>`** you could also adjust your `@WebParam` to add `targetNamespace` as follows:

```
 @WebParam(name = "eventId", targetNamespace="http://ws.udc.es/event") Long eventId
```

When I change my service provider this way, the output is reversed and `<eve:eventId>` is no longer `null`.

Comment: This should be accepted as a solution. Adding `targetNamespace` helped me to solve similar problem.